# How do I connect my local DNS server to provider's?

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, dns

I have bought a domain name from GoDaddy and I have my old PC acting as a server. I want to setup my DNS server that will be responsible for subdomains, whereas GoDaddy has its own DNS server responsible for my second-level domain name.

I have troubles "connecting" provider's DNS server to mine. What records do I need to put into GoDaddy's DNS management console and into my BIND config?

Here are entries at GoDaddy:

```
A       @               84.23.37.194                            1 h
cname   ftp             @                                       1 h
cname   www             @                                       1 h
cname   _domainconnect  _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com     1 h
ns      @               ns31.domaincontrol.com                  1 h
ns      @               ns32.domaincontrol.com                  1 h
```

I added one additional entry:

```
ns  @               ns.xobotun.com                          1 h
```

Here are my BIND settings:

• file `\etc\bind\named.conf.local`:

```
zone "xobotun.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.xobotun.com";
};
```

• file `\etc\bind\db.xobotun.com`:

```
$TTL    604800
xobotun.com     IN      SOA     ns31.domaincontrol.com. hostmaster.godaddy.com. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL

xobotun.com.    IN      NS      ns31.domaincontrol.com.
xobotun.com.    IN      NS      ns32.domaincontrol.com.
xobotun.com.    IN      A       84.23.37.194

static          IN      A       84.23.37.194
cv              IN      A       84.23.37.194
ns              IN      A       84.23.37.194
```

I suppose that I should alter the line I added to GoDaddy DNS control panel, but it does not let me enter plain ip address and asks to enter DNS server address in `nsXX.nameserver.tld` format.

I've been fighting DNS server two days already and gave up. Of course, I can add a string like
`A    static    @    1h` to GoDaddy control panel, but that is way too easy!

**EDIT**

I ran `nmap` and found a discrepancy: responding service was not `BIND`, but `pdnsd`. That lead me to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems:

1. I had previously installed `pdnsd` as caching DNS server. Even though I have turned it off, it started its daemon every time I was launching `service bind9 restart`. And yes, it occupied `0.0.0.0` and seemed to respond instead of `bind9`, however not showing itself in `netstat -tulpn`. I figured it only after launching `nmap` from another PC.
2. There was anti-mitm-alike protection on: https://askubuntu.com/questions/768210/bind9-will-not-resolve.
3. Finally and mainly, after several iterations of editing `\etc\bind\db.xobotun.com`, I accidentally removed point `.`
   `xobotun.com     IN      SOA     ns31.domaincontrol.com. hostmaster.godaddy.com. (`

   It should instead looked like
   `xobotun.com.     IN      SOA     ns31.domaincontrol.com. hostmaster.godaddy.com. (`

   `___________↑`

It is working now, thanks!